# is it possible to use await in a sync function in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function to get the user login status, now I want to add a logic with silent login when checked user did not login.After the user log, I store the login information about user name and password into local secure storage after the user login for the first time, when invoke the `islogin` function, my code looks like this:

```
bool get isLogin {
    if(this == null){
      // not login, do the automatic login logic
      final UserAccount userAccount = UserAccount();
      final String? phone = await SecureStorageUtil.getString("username");
      final String? password = await SecureStorageUtil.getString("password");
      if(phone == null || password == null){
        return false;
      }
      final Result<Map> result = await userAccount.login(phone, password);
      if(result != null){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return this != null;
  }
```

what make me stuck is that the fetch credential information and login was async and have to using await keywords to wait the return. But the await keyword only allow in async function.

```
The await expression can only be used in an async function.
```

If I change the `isLogin` function to async, many places in this project must change. I was wonder is it possible to using await in the sync function? so I could do the auto login if the user logined for only one time. And did not do any change with the previous code.

Comment: What if try to replace function signature onto 
`Future<bool> get isLogin async {`

Comment: 1. `await` is a contextual keyword that is enabled only with `async`, so by definition it is impossible to use `await` without `async`. 2. `await` is syntactic sugar for setting up a `Future.then()` callback. 3. If you want a fire-and-forget asynchronous function where you don't need or want callers to be notified when it completes, just make your function `async` with a `void` return type.

Comment: if I change the function to async, many relate places must changed by this change. @ThomasAnderson

Comment: I found a function waitFor should do this, but it seems should not use in flutter client. the code should look like this:  `String phone = waitFor<String>(Future.value());` @jamesdlin

Comment: Using `waitFor` is strongly discouraged.  You either must accept that your callers must `await` the result of your function, or you should redesign your API so that the value is initialized separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace you function signature with

```
Future<bool> get isLogin async {
```

Comment: I can not change like this, too much places invoke this function, if I changed, so much places should changed follow this change.@Thomas Anderson

Answer (score 0):

```
Timer timer;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer timer) async {
      await this.getUserVerificationInfo();
  });
}

@override
void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    timer.cancel();
}

getUserVerificationInfo() async {
   await someAsyncFunc();
   timer.cancle();
}
```

Comment: The `Timer` is superfluous.  It adds an extra delay but provides no benefit to just calling `someAsyncFunc()` without `await`.